# How can I pass a result of a query to a function?

Tags: pointers, cppcms

I want to do something like this

```
function A(){
    session database_handler(....);

    result res = database_handler << "SELECT ....";

    functionB(res);
}
```

what should the parameters of functionB be?

Passing it as a pointer does not work, neither as in the example.

Thanks

Comment: "It does not work" is not a very accurate description.

Comment: It's true but I'm not sure what happens (maybe an empty copy is made), so I preferred to aviod details, also because I think that it is an easy question for somebody working with cppdb.

Comment: The API doc says that the reference is copied, but the data isn't. Still, during what happens in `functionB` the data should be there, `res` only goes out of scope at the end of `A()`. Have you made sure  that there is data in `res` when you check it in `A()`?

Comment: I finally find the error. I was using the same functionB for iterating over multiple results as for over only one. When I thought about the only one result case, I write `if(!result.next()) // There are no results`. That sentence advanced the pointer and made the fetching fail. Thanks for your help.

Comment: How are you linking?  Would you mind helping with this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23436959/how-to-include-link-cppdb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely copy `cppdb::result` but you may iterate over it only in one location. i.e. `cppdb::result` holds a reference (counted) to the result object so if you iterate over rows in `functionB` you can't iterate over them in `functionA`

So you can safely define

```
void functionB(cppdb::result res);
```

However it would be the same in terms of iterating as

```
void functionB(cppdb::result &res);
```

Also the last one faster as it does not involve reference counting overhead.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to create a structure similar to your result set.
populate that structure and pass a structure pointer to function.

other way is to declare your function as functionB(result res) i.e. it accepts parameters of type result and then extract query result from "res"

Comment: The second way is the one I was using, but I was making a mistake inside functionB. It is solved, thanks!